# AJAX not triggering preset function using PDO to retrieve from database

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Having this part in an HTML form, working in PHP for server-side backend. Need the user to select country and based on the country the city list is refined to that particular country cities only. AJAX is refreshing and passing the variables but the PHP function is not triggering:

```
// PHP part
$action = "all";

if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
    $action = $_POST['action'];
}

if (isset($_GET['action'])) {
    $action = $_GET['action'];
}
```

```
<label class="form-text" id="further-details-labels" for="country">Country:</label>
    <select onchange="getCountry(this.value)" class="form-control country" name="country" id="country">
        <?php
        echo "<option value=\"\">Please select Country</option>";
        foreach ($model->getCountry() AS $countries => $country) {
            echo "<option value={$country['country_code']}>{$country['country_name']}</option>";
        }
        ?>
    </select>

    <label class="form-text" id="further-details-labels" for="city">City:</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="city" id="further-details-input">
        <option value="">Please select City</option>
        <?php
        switch ($action) {
            case "all": 
                $model = new model();
                foreach ($model->getCity() AS $cities => $city) {
                    echo "<option value={$city['city_code']}>{$city['city_name']}</option>";
                } 
            break;
            case 'country': 
                $country = $_POST['country']; 
                $model = new model();
                foreach ($model->getCityByCountry($country) as $cities => $city) {
                    echo "<option value={$city['city_code']}>{$city['city_name']}</option>";
                } 
            break;// to continue switch statement and add ajax calls
        }
        ?>
    </select>
```

AJAX

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// TODO fetching script for onchange
function getCountry(country_code) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        var xhr = new ActiveObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var country = {"country": country_code};
            console.log(country);
            var test = document.getElementById("test");
//                    test.innerHTML=this.responseText;
        }

    };
    xhr.open("POST","details.php", true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.send("action=country&country="+country);
};
</script>
```

Any suggestion as to how to connect them to make the select options change based on the function triggered please?

Comment: FYI, PHP has `$_REQUEST` that combines `$_POST` and `$_GET`, so you don't need the two `if` statements.

Comment: When the PHP script is responding to the AJAX request, it should not output the entire page, it should just output the `<option>` elements for the city menu. Then you can put that into the `innerHTML` of the city menu.

Comment: That's exactly what it does, the $model->getCityByCountry() is a pdo statement that executes in php, all I need ajax is to pass the variable country inside it for the where clause and execute the foreach to generate the <option>. You are right in saying though that at the moment it is outputting all the form for some reason, cannot figure out why....

Comment: Why shouldn't it? You have nothing stopping it from outputting the rest of the form.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check `$action` before printing the rest of the form, not inside the form. If it's `all` you print the whole form, if it's `country` you just print the country options.

```
<?php
switch ($action) {
case "all":
    ?>
    <label class="form-text" id="further-details-labels" for="country">Country:</label>
    <select onchange="getCountry(this.value)" class="form-control country" name="country" id="country">
        <?php
        echo "<option value=\"\">Please select Country</option>";
        foreach ($model->getCountry() AS $countries => $country) {
            echo "<option value={$country['country_code']}>{$country['country_name']}</option>";
        }
        ?>
    </select>

    <label class="form-text" id="further-details-labels" for="city">City:</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="city" id="further-details-input">
        <option value="">Please select City</option>
        <?php
        $model = new model();
        foreach ($model->getCity() AS $cities => $city) {
            echo "<option value={$city['city_code']}>{$city['city_name']}</option>";
        }
        ?>
    </select>
        <?php
        break;

case 'country': 
    $country = $_POST['country']; 
    $model = new model();
    foreach ($model->getCityByCountry($country) as $cities => $city) {
        echo "<option value={$city['city_code']}>{$city['city_name']}</option>";
    } 
    break;// to continue switch statement and add ajax calls
}
```

Then in the AJAX code, the callback function should do:

```
document.querySelector("select[name=city]").innerHTML = this.responseText;
```

Comment: The form is printed upon the page loads, there are other details that need filling in. What it is meant to do is make the user first choose his country, then instead of showing all cities it shows only cities that are of that chosen country. I made the switch to trigger which function is needed depending on the user choice so when a country is chosen it should trigger the 2nd function instead of the general getCity() and output only that select instead.

Comment: That's the idea of this. On page load, `$action` defaults to `all`, so it prints the whole form. When it's called from AJAX with `action=country`, it skips over that and just returns the options for the city menu.

Comment: now I get this: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Thanks a lot Barmar, the internal server error was only a pair of missing brackets in the model executing PDO statement. All resolved now and works wonders. Cheers :)